# What risks are assumed by using ProGuard optimizations?

Tags: android, proguard

Targeting `android-19` but using `Android Support Library v4` to allow my app to run on Android 2.2 and later.

I'm currently experimenting with ProGuard optimizations, using the configuration file `proguard-android-optimize.txt` (available in the SDK). It states:

> Adding optimization introduces certain risks, since for example not
>   all optimizations performed by ProGuard works on all versions of
>   Dalvik

Risky business huh? But just how risky is it? Certainly, lots of apps on Google Play have been optimized using ProGuard. It says `not... all versions of Dalvik`. What does this mean? Are there different versions of Dalvik in Android?

How does ProGuard increase your risk, exactly?

Comment: Can't understand the nonsense of using proguard for Android apps then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you over-optimize (in particular via code obfuscation), you can have unexpected results in your code (certain calls may not work).

It is an art to use proguard, and you should test extensively using different proguard settings, to ensure you aren't breaking any functionality.